# Forming a chemical formula from a string of elements python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to ask a question about converting a list of items into a string.

I have the following list of a SiH2O molecule, where the 2 implies the subscript of 2 hydrogen atoms:

```
[['Si', array([0, 1, 2])], 
['H', array([3, 4, 5])], 
['O', array([6, 7, 8])],
['H', array([3, 4, 5])]]
```

My intention is to convert this data into a chemical formulae i.e. SiH2O.

Another example is shown below:

```
['H', array([3, 4, 5])], 
['F', array([6, 7, 8])],
['H', array([3, 4, 5])]]
```

I am attempting to convert this to `H2F` (without any subscript formatting - I purely want to reach the `H2F` output.)

My attempt so far is as follows:

I first looped through the string to retrieve all the chemical symbols:

```
symbols = []
for item in string:
    symbols.append(item[0])
symbols
```

I then tried to find the unique atoms in the string (i.e. a string of elements that are only repeated once in the string):

```
unique = []
for i in symbols:
    if i not in unique:
        unique.append(i)
```

And this returned

```
['Si', 'H', 'O']
```

and

```
['H', 'F']
```

respectively.

I attempted to create a dictionary of the elements and their count, with an original default of 0:

```
myDict = {key:0 for key in unique}
```

and then attempted to count through the dictionary.

```
for item in symbols:
    count = myDict[item]
    count += 1
    myDict[item] = count
```

This returns:

```
{'Si': 1, 'H': 2, 'O': 1}
```

Now, I want to use the `key, value` pair to compile the string `SiH2O`. I used the condition `if value == 1` then I would not attach the subscript number after the chemical symbol.

This was the code I attempted.

```
chemical_string = ""
for key, value in symbols:
    if value == 0:
        chemical_string += key
    else:
        chemical_string += key + "" + value
```

I expected the result `SiH2O` but I fall into this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-d5312c683c2e> in <module>
      1 chemical_string = ""
----> 2 for key, value in myDict:
      3     if value == 0:
      4         chemical_string += key
      5     else:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I'm confused on why this doesn't work. How can I solve this matter?

Comment: If you want to iterate over `key, value` pairs of a dictionary, you need `myDict.items()`. Iterating over only `myDict` will give you just the keys which, in your case, could not be "unpacked" into two separate values.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Luka Mensaric's answer, I need to use the `.items()` method.

I also realised I need to convert `value` into a `str` inside the `else` statement:

```
chemical_string = ""
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if value == 1:
        chemical_string += key
    else:
        chemical_string += key + "" + str(value)
```

Comment: You can safely remove `""` in the last line. Also, the part where you had `count += 1` can be shortened to just `myDict[item] += 1`.